# Using createjs, preoloading and caching, why is my canvas still so slow?

Tags: html, canvas, bitmap, createjs

I am trying to create a small RPG for class. I create one Bitmap image, cache it, and then every time I need that same Bitmap, I clone it, and finally add them to the stage. However, despite my efforts, my canvas is still extremely slow since I am drawing all of these bushes.

I would put them in a container, however, I need to know the X and Y position that way I know if the player is trying to step over their boundaries.

Here is my function:

```
  parseRoom: function(mapObject, room, obj, image){
            var letter = 'X';
            //var object = obj;
            var object = null;
            var img = new createjs.Bitmap(image);
            for(var m=0; m < mapObject.length; m++){
                for(var j=0; j< mapObject[m].length; j++){

                    letter = mapObject[j][m];

                    switch (letter){
                        case 'X': 
                        //do nothing
                        break;
                        case 'O':    
                        //object = this.createObject();
                        //object.image = img.clone();
                        img.cache();
                        object = img.clone();

                        room.AddObstacle(object, m, j);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

and this is my function when I actually add them to the stage:

```
   addObstacle: function(imgObj, x, y){
                imgObj.x = x ||imgObj.x || 0;
                imgObj.y = y ||imgObj.y || 0;
                imgObj.setVisible = function(visible){
                  this.visible = visible;  
                };
                imgObj.update = function(){
                  if(this.visible)this.visible= true;
                    else this.visible = false;
                };
                objects.push(imgObj);
                stage.addChild(imgObj);
            },
```

as you can see, I extend the Bitmap class and also add and update and a setVisible method to it. That way I can turn them all off or on depending on the screen. Any ideas that could help me and make my game smoother? Thank you!

[image: My canvas map]

Answer (score 0):

I was constantly updating every object, including the bushes, and there was no need to update the bushes every tick. I simply removed logic from checking the bushes and now it runs really fast.